# Excel Substitute given values and delete non given values

Tags: excel

I have 3 columns named `Old Model, New Model, & Obsolete Model`. The `New Model` should be the output and is the New name from the `Old Model` table which is the input where as: `AB`
 should be `IJ`, `CD` should be `KL`, and `EF`should be `MN`. The `Obsolete Model` containing `GH` should not be included in the output of column `New Model`.

```
Old Model     New Model    Obsolete Model
AB,CD,EF,GH   IJ,KL,MN     GH
```

I can simply use the `Substitute` excel formula for this one which goes like this:

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"AB","IJ"),"CD","KL"),"EF","MN")`

The problem with this formula is that it will still show `GH` in the `New Model` column.

Can Anyone help me with this one? I have more than 1000 lines and within are different `Old Model` different `New Model` and different `Obsolete Model`

Is there a simple approch for this one without using VBA codes since the fili I am running is quite big and I'm affraid it might slow down the process.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Extract one old model from the cell like this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("CD",A1),(len("CD")))

Result: AB,CD,EF,GH --> CD
```

Concatenate as many of those sequences as necessary to isolate all your old models.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("AB",A1),(len("AB")))&MID(A1,FIND("CD",A1),(len("CD")))&MID(A1,FIND("EF",A1),(len("EF")))
```

Then in a separate column, you an apply your original substitute formula to the result.

---

Add another substitute statement and substitute "GH" with nothing, "".

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"AB","IJ"),"CD","KL"),"EF","MN"), "GH", "")
```

Then to isolate "GH" in the obsolete column, just replace all the other values with nothing.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"AB",""),"CD",""),"EF",""), "GH", "")
```

Make sure to add commas to the strings to be replaced if you want to get rid of those also, i.e. "AB,", "CD,", "EF,".

Comment: But there are a hundred more values for the `Obsolete Model`. It's not just `GH` itself. The formula would run more than 100 `substitute` function if I am to do that code. Regards

Comment: Are the obsolete models always to the right as in your example or can they show up anywhere in the cell such as "AB,GH,CD,EF"?

Comment: They are in ramdom order. It may come in the middle just like your example.

Comment: the `mid find len` formula you posted will just remove the commas. What I need is a shortcut since there are more than 100 values for the `Obsolete Model`. if i'm going to do this in your approach, my formula will be super long. Regards

Comment: The mid find len approach will **separate the old models to be substituted from your obsolete models**.  You don't need to specify what is obsolete, you just need to specify what you want from the old.  Then once you have what you want from the old, you can substitute them with the new.

Comment: Excellent @chishaku. I didn't get the idea at first. Thank you!